# Trouble running Contoso Cookbook Samples with no changes made

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I am going through the Contoso Cookbook examples from the Microsoft Virtual Academy Windows Jumpstart for Windows Phone 8.  In trying to run any of the sample code, I get 3 deployment errors.

1. "The parameter is incorrect"
2. The member "Instance" is not recognized or is not accessible
3. The property "Instance was not found in type "DesignDataExtension"

In the xaml code on the mainPage.xaml line 35, it is not recognizing "Instance".  but I cannot figure out the cause.

Can anyone tell me why?

[Code samples link](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2013/01/15/Windows-Phone-8-Jumpstart-Content-and-Samples.aspx)

[Video Series Link](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start-01a-Introducing-Windows-Phone-8-Development-Part-1)

Comment: It would help if you told us which sample you can't run. I've opened two of them at random, and none of them has any "DesignDataExtension"

Comment: Step 6: Page Navigation  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Phone-8-JumpStart-1b7c34e3

Comment: mainPage.xaml line 35  LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" d:DataContext="{d:DesignData /SampleData/RecipeDataSourceSampleData.xaml, Instance={x:Null}}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's two problems.

The first one (parameter is incorrect) is preventing the application from being deployed. To fix it, remove the "%2c" from the folder name (the default folder name is "Windows Phone 8 JumpStart Contoso Cookbook Step 1%2c Initial Layout", it seems to make the deploy process bug somehow). Then delete the `ContosoCookbook.suo` and `ContosoCookbook.v11.suo` files located in the C# subfolder.

The second error doesn't prevent the application from working, but crashes the designer. In the attributes of the grid (MainPage.xaml, line 38) :

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" d:DataContext="{d:DesignData /SampleData/RecipeDataSourceSampleData.xaml, Instance={x:Null}}">
```

Remove the `, Instance={x:Null}` part and it'll work just fine:

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" d:DataContext="{d:DesignData /SampleData/RecipeDataSourceSampleData.xaml}">
```